# How would I format code that a function is pasting into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a user doubleclicks on my textarea, default text appears in the box.  The text is code so I'd like to to be formatted in a readable way but I cant seem to figure out how to format the code I'm pasting in with JavaScript.

```
function initialHTML(){

    document.getElementById("html").value = "<h3>Greetings!</h3>"
                                            +
                                            "<p>Start by adding some HTML and CSS </p>"
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what results from the code you've posted, and what you want to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a textarea, have you tried utilizing the innerHTML instead? Something like:
document.getElementById(“html”).innerHTML = *insert html here*

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, "I want to perform syntax highlighting and other styling changes on the text inside of a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)", you can't. You'd need to pick a different element because the only "permitted content" is one or more [Text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)

If you mean, "I want to add line breaks and other formatting inside the string"...Easy, either manually add in the whitespace characters like `\n` or create the string using a template literal, which allows line breaks in its syntax. For example:

Manually adding `\n`:

```js
function initialHTML() {
  document.getElementById("html").value =
    '<h3>Greetings!</h3>\n' +
    '<p>Start by adding some HTML and CSS </p>'
}

initialHTML()
```

```css
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<textarea id="html"></textarea>
```

Using template literals:

```js
function initialHTML() {
  document.getElementById("html").value =
`<h3>Greetings!</h3>
<p>Start by adding some HTML and CSS </p>`
}

initialHTML()
```

```css
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<textarea id="html"></textarea>
```